# Reverse a stack without using extra data structure.Is it really possible?

Tags: algorithm, stack

The answer for the above question is that you use function call stack to store stack and then push them onto the original stack to be reversed once it is empty. But even here are not using extra space whilst using function call stack for storage?

Comment: Yes. The call stack definitely takes space. I don't think you can reverse a stack with o(n) extra space (small-oh)

Comment: So using recursion is the same as using another stack right?

Comment: Yeah basically.